# Signos de exclamación en definiciones graphQL. ¿Cómo los uso correctamente?

Tags: graphql

Tengo una duda con graphQL (en realidad tengo muchisimas porque apenas comencé a usarlo, pero esta es puntual)

Imaginemos que yo declaro un `type`, por ejemplo `Usuarios`.

```
type Usuario {
    username: String!
    password: String!
}
```

Y luego tengo la query `Usuarios`

```
Querys {
    getUsuarios: [Usuario]!
}
```

Si yo a esta query le defino que en lugar de retornar {Users} , lo destructure y le oculte el password de esta manera

```
{ ...Users, password: null }
```

Es cuando me entran todas las preguntas.

El hecho de que yo en el tipo `Usuario` haya definido `password: String!` hace que el backend, al querer devolverme el usuario creado con la contraseña en null, me arroje un error diciendo que no puede retornar null de una propiedad no-nullable.

> Entonces, cual es la forma correcta de decir que una variable debe ser de un tipo estricto, pero a su vez poder ''nullearla'' por si fuera un dato sensible??

Por otro lado no entiendo bien la diferencia entre devolver [Usuario], [Usuario!], [Usuario]! o [Usuario!]!

Desde ya muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo también estoy estudiando `graphQL`, comparto mis notas.

---

Se quiere consultar una lista de usuarios con `graphQL query language`:

```
Querys {
    getUsuarios: [Usuario]!
}
```

El `resolver Query` espera **una lista tipo [Usuario] con cero o mas valores**, definidos en el `Object type Usuario`.

---

#### List Object Type con signo de exclamación

Con el signo de exclamación "!", se especifica que una lista no puede recibir un valor tipo `null`. Si la lista recibiera este valor, `graphQL` regresaría el siguiente mensaje:

> "message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable field Query.getUsuarios."

```
"data": null
```

Aquí quiero dejar un punto muy claro:

> El Query getUsuarios puede regresar una lista vacía [] (zero or more values), mas no un tipo null.

---

#### List Object type sin signo de exclamación

Si se definiera el Query sin "!" en la lista `[Usuario]`:

```
Querys {
        getUsuarios: [Usuario]
    }
```

Al hacer la consulta, suponiendo que la lista `[Usuario]` por alguna razón viene como un valor tipo `null`,  graphQL regresaría el siguiente mensaje:

```
"data": {
    "getUsuarios": null
  }
```

---

#### Object type con signo de exclamación

Si se definiera el Query con doble "!", uno para la lista `[Usuario]` y otro para el type `Usuario`:

```
Querys {
        getUsuarios: [Usuario!]!
    }
```

Se esta especificando, para el tipo `Usuario`, que todos los fields de cada elemento de la lista `Usuario` deben estar incluidos.

Por ejemplo, si la lista `Usuarios` tuviera tan solo un elemento `Usuario` donde no existera el field `password`, graphQL regresaría el siguiente mensaje:

> "message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable field Usuario.password."

Y más importante, **los otros elementos de la lista quedarían descartados**, aunque estos si tuvieran el field `password`,  graphQL regresaría el siguiente mensaje:

```
 "data": null
```

---

#### Object type sin signo de exclamación

Si se definiera el Query sin "!" en el type `Usuario`:

```
Querys {
        getUsuarios: [Usuario]!
    }
```

Se esta especificando que **no todos** los fields de cada elemento de la lista `Usuario` deben estar incluidos.

Por ejemplo, si la lista `Usuarios` tuviera tan solo un elemento `Usuario` donde no existera el field `password`, graphQL regresaría el siguiente mensaje:

> "message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable field Usuario.password."

Sin embargo, graphQL **si regresaria** los elementos de la lista que tuvieran el field `password`.